# Difference between Synclock and WaitOne

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, synclock

I've used a thread managed waiter.

SyncLock
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3a86s51t%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

But now, I wanted to have a timeout and found the WaitOne.

WaitOne
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone.aspx
which supports a simple timeout.

But it does not work anymore. It can be that the fault is somewhere else in the code. My main question to you is, is there a difference between using `SyncLock` and `WaitOne` as basic waiter flag?

Regards

Comment: SyncLock = enter a lock, WaitOne = wait for an event.  They have nothing in common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx

> Using a lock or monitor is useful for preventing the simultaneous
>   execution of thread-sensitive blocks of code, but these constructs do
>   not allow one thread to communicate an event to another. This requires
>   synchronization events, which are objects that have one of two states,
>   signaled and un-signaled, that can be used to activate and suspend
>   threads. Threads can be suspended by being made to wait on a
>   synchronization event that is unsignaled, and can be activated by
>   changing the event state to signaled. If a thread attempts to wait on
>   an event that is already signaled, then the thread continues to
>   execute without delay.
>
> There are two kinds of synchronization events: AutoResetEvent, and
>   ManualResetEvent. They differ only in that AutoResetEvent changes from
>   signaled to unsignaled automatically any time it activates a thread.
>   Conversely, a ManualResetEvent allows any number of threads to be
>   activated by its signaled state, and will only revert to an unsignaled
>   state when its Reset method is called.
>
> Threads can be made to wait on events by calling one of the wait
>   methods, such as WaitOne, WaitAny, or WaitAll. WaitHandle.WaitOne()
>   causes the thread to wait until a single event becomes signaled,
>   WaitHandle.WaitAny() blocks a thread until one or more indicated
>   events become signaled, and WaitHandle.WaitAll() blocks the thread
>   until all of the indicated events become signaled. An event becomes
>   signaled when its Set method is called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seemt that I am not very familar with AutoResetEvents on so galled signaled threads. Perhaps I just do not understand English words at all. As far as I understood is the difference that WaitOne can be managed manually.

Comment: Yes, WaitOne will block until you call Set() on the AutoResetEvent. You would call the Set event from another thread or async method for instance.  Here is a link to an example of waitOne that I use.  In the example WaitOne  is being used to block until an IE web page completes a navigation. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7337204/930990

Answer (score 4):

`SyncLock` is a language specific wrapper for `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit`. It is intended to be used to restrict simultaneously access to a critical section of code or resource.

`WaitHandle.WaitOne` is a method that is intended to be used in scenarios where a thread should wait for an external signal. The exact implementation and semantics of how it works is class specific. In other words, `WaitOne` will behave differently when used from an `AutoResetEvent` as compared to a `ManualResetEvent` or `Semaphore`.

The two are really targeted for different use cases. Without a better description of your specific problem it is difficult to even speculate which one is best to use.

However, if you know for certain that you want the semantics of a lock (via `SyncLock` or the `Monitor` class) then you can use `Monitor.TryEnter` which does provide a timeout parameter.

Comment: Thanks Brian. That already makes sense. I need to synchronize video captured images while processing on the frames. For example grayscale it. But it is not a default frame sequence because other threads can raise the event for interupting other frames. As far as I understand, WaitOne will be my solution.