# ShellWindows() not getting second internet explorer window c#

Tags: c#

I am working on automation on IE 8 for one application. I am trying to get the second IE window which is opened from first window. But in ShellWindows I am getting only the first window. Herewith the code I am using:

```
InternetExplorer IE = null;
ShellWindows m_IEFoundBrowsers = new ShellWindowsClass();
foreach (InternetExplorer Browser in m_IEFoundBrowsers)
{
Logger.Log("Hi I am StatusText :" + Browser.StatusText + ", Url name : " + Browser.LocationURL + ", HWND : " + Browser.HWND);
if (Browser.HWND == IEPtr.ToInt32())
{
     IE = Browser;
     break;
}
}
if (IE == null)
          throw new Exception("Error in creating Internet explorer instance");
```

But it seems I am not getting the second window (Browser.HWND). I have run the same code in other system and its working fine. I was just wondering is there any IE setting which i am missing in my system.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any one, please suggest me if you have any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer help? It sounded like it was the same issue you're running into:

[Active tab ignored by InternetExplorer COM object for IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337204/active-tab-ignored-by-internetexplorer-com-object-for-ie-8)